# como puedo validar un Input type file para que el nombre del archivo que recoja no tenga caracteres especiales

Tags: php, html5, ajax

Ya intente utilizar la validacion de html5 para indicarle que solo acepte letras minúsculas pero no funciona. Estoy utilizando lo siguiente para tomar el archivo y el script siguiente para mandarlo al php donde sera procesado.

```
<input id='file-0d' class='file' type='file' name='pdf' accept='application/pdf' required data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Selecciona un Archivo PDF con un nombre en minúsculas y sin caracteres especiales como: *#%@.,ñ '>
```

el script es este:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('submit', '#formsubpdf', function() { 

    var data = $(this).serialize();  

    $.ajax({  
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '../subirpdf.php',
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
              cache: false,
        processData:false,

        success :  function(data) {  
            $('#formsubpdf')[0].reset();
            //$("#ofertastrab").html(data);
             if (data=="1") {

          alert ('Ocurrio un problema al momento de guardar por favor intente de nuevo mas tarde ');    
        }else{alert ('Subido con Exito');}  
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

});

Comment: quieres validarlo con antes del evento ajax o quieres validarlo en el php???

Comment: quiero validar ya sea en el php o antes del ajax ya que para mandarlo utilizo el serialize en el script y ay no puedo verificar en especifico ese input

Comment: hay te deje un par de ejemplos para los dos lenguajes. saludos

Comment: ¿Quieres evitar la subida si los nombres son incorrectos o filtrar los caracteres no permitidos (eliminarlos o sustituirlos por algo, como un guión bajo `_`, u otro carácter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno mira con ajax seria algo asi:

```
var isValid=(function(){
  var rg1=/^[^\\/:\*\?"<>\|]+$/; // caracteres prohibidos \ / : * ? " < > |
  var rg2=/^\./; // cannot start with dot (.)
  var rg3=/^(nul|prn|con|lpt[0-9]|com[0-9])(\.|$)/i; // Nombres prohibidos para archivos
  return function isValid(fname){
    return rg1.test(fname)&&!rg2.test(fname)&&!rg3.test(fname);
  }
})();

isValid('file name');
```

de lado del PHP creo que seria algo asi pero puedes mejorarlo:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+\.ext$/', $file)) {
    // .. upload
} else {
    echo 'The file "' . $file . '"was not uploaded. The file can only contain "a-z", "0-9" and "-". Allso the files must be lowercase. ';

}
```